# How do I add "Closed/Lost" as filter option for opportunity status?

Tags: reporting, opportunity, dashboard, filters, closedate

Why is "Closed/Lost" not showing up as an option? In the report, I know that we have opportunities that are closed/lost.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is working-as-designed

To get lost opportunities:

- choose `Opportunity Status = Closed` which gets closed won and closed lost
- add an additional filter for the field `IsWon` = false